# Вывод переменных в одной строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, вывод, print

```py
number1 = input("Введите первое число:") 
print("Вы ввели:", number1)

number2 = input("Введите второе число:") 
print("Вы ввели:", number2)

if number2 == "0": 
    print("Поделить невозможно")

print("Результат деления =", int(number1) / int(number2))
```

Единственное НО: не могу разобраться, как вывести первое число, поделенное на второе число и ответ...
Как это так вывести?

Comment: *как вывести число 1 поделенное на число 2 и ответ* – но ответ это и есть число 1 поделенное на число 2. В чём проблема? И да, если бы Вы прочитали справку, прежде чем писать вопрос, Вы бы знали, что нужно подробно описать желаемое поведение программы и то, которое есть сейчас.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его галочкой как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

```
number1 = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
print(f"Вы ввели: {number1}")
number2 = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
print(f"Вы ввели: {number2}")
try:
    result = number1 / number2
    print(f"Результат деления = {result}")
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(f"Поделить невозможно {e}")
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, подскажите что значит эта строка, с ней я ещё не сталкивался.
except ZeroDivisionError as e:

Comment: @ДенисОчеретнюк [except](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/advanced_python/lessons/python_exceptions/theory_unit) - механизм исключений

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял "как вывести число 1 поделенное на число 2 и ответ", и нужно в одной строке указать и делимое, и делитель, и результат, тогда так:

```
number_1 = int(input('Введите первое число:'))
number_2 = int(input('Введите второе число:'))

if number_2: 
    result = number_1 / number_2
    print(f'Результат деления {number_1} на {number_2} равен {result}')
else:
    print('Поделить на 0 невозможно')
```

результат:

```
Введите первое число:>? 3
Введите второе число:>? 2
Результат деления 3 на 2 равен 1.5
```

и при number_2 равном 0:

```
Введите первое число:>? 42
Введите второе число:>? 0
Поделить на 0 невозможно
```

- `if number_2:` отработает, если number_2 не равен 0;
- для вывода используйте [f-строки](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python), в которых укажите переменные

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь
{} - подскажите для чего эти скобки ? какую функцию они выполняют. так как с ними я ещё не сталкивался

Comment: фигурные скобки в пайтоновской  [f-строке](https://python-scripts.com/f-strings) ограничивают переменную или выражение, результат которого будет выведиться на печать... такой синтаксис